# How to move the H1 to be inline with the top of the DIV

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble making the `<h2 class="feature_description_content">` vertically align with the image to it's left. You can see that it's quite a bit lower than the top of the image, and I can't seem to find the css that is responsible for it.

Here's an image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="feature feature-item-248">
                <img class="main" src="http://www.bolistylus.com/wp-content/uploads/uclaproduct.png" alt="" /></p>
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">PERFECTLY WEIGHTED</h2>

</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">
<p>Touch screens have simplified technology, but there has yet to be a way to capture the precision of a calligrapher or the stroke of an artist. Not only should it meet your needs, but a stylus should have style.</p>
</div></div>
</p></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its `margin-top: 0;` - simple :)

Answer (score 3):

This issues is must be due to default margin and padding of default HTML elements you must try out by setting

`h2
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }`

and then change padding as required

Answer (score 0):

The image suppose to be floated to the left and cleared both ways, so text can be aligned properly...

```
 img .main {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 }
```